# SQL Nested Joins (Case Statement and Join)

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, case

Hive DBMS; Two tables -- A and B

**Table A**

```
prnt_id      sub_id      ac_nm      cost    units
unknown      abc01       abc corp   34500   24
unknown      unknown     xyz corp   9800    10
856          abc03       jfk corp   9820    12
```

**Table B**

```
prnt_id      sub_id      ac_nm 
123          abc01       abc corp
456          abc02       xyz corp
856          abc03       jfk corp
859          abc04       ops corp
```

**Question** --> Trying to execute a query where:
Join table A with table B, first on prnt_id, if it's "unknown", then join on sub_id, if that is "unknown", join on ac_nm

**Desired Output**:

```
prnt_id      sub_id      ac_nm      cost    units
123          abc01       abc corp   34500   24
456          abc02       xyz corp   9800    10
856          abc03       jfk corp   9820    12
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is `unknown`? Do you mean `null`?

Comment: No, unknown is string value or it could be NULL, both conditions could exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `LEFT` joins of `TableB` to 3 copies of `TableA` and filter out the non matching rows:

```
select b.*,
       coalesce(a1.cost, a2.cost, a3.cost) cost,
       coalesce(a1.units, a2.units, a3.units) units
from TableB b
left join TableA a1 on a1.prnt_id = b.prnt_id
left join TableA a2 on a2.sub_id = b.sub_id and a1.prnt_id is null
left join TableA a3 on a3.ac_nm = b.ac_nm and a2.sub_id is null
where coalesce(a1.prnt_id, a2.sub_id, a3.ac_nm) is not null
order by b.prnt_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTZx3hBse9radwDagNnvRj/0).
Results:

```
| prnt_id | sub_id | ac_nm    | cost  | units |
| ------- | ------ | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| 123     | abc01  | abc corp | 34500 | 24    |
| 456     | abc02  | xyz corp | 9800  | 10    |
| 856     | abc03  | jfk corp | 9820  | 12    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`s and `coalesce()` to choose the first match:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.?, bs.?, ba.?) as new_col
from a left join
     b
     on b.prnt_id = a.prnt_id left join
     b bs
     on bs.sub_id = a.sub_id and b.prnt_id is null left join
     b ba
     on bs.ac_nm = a.ac_num and bs.sub_id is null;
```